# expandable listview indicator display title height?

Tags: android, expandablelistview, indicator

I have using a expandable listview with Group indicator display right side of the list, in this i have title name is single line my output like this

[image]

in above image my indicator is looking good.
in the below image my indicator looking not good it expand, why this happen

[image]

here is my code

```
    mExpandableList = (ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.expandable_list);
    mExpandableList.setIndicatorBounds(width - GetPixelFromDips(40), width - GetPixelFromDips(10));
```

xml is

```
     <ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/expandable_list"        
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:groupIndicator="@drawable/group_indicator" />
```

group_indicator.xml is

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/arrow_down"     android:state_expanded="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/arrow_up"/>
</selector>
```

Any one have idea help this one........

Comment: Which layout are you using for group items?

Comment: @AlexBcn linearlayout.........

Answer (score 2):

I solve this problem more complex way but it works:

Fragment of layout file with expandable list:

```
<ExpandableListView
  android:id="@+id/accordion"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:groupIndicator="@android:color/transparent"
  android:scrollbars="none" >
</ExpandableListView>
```

Layout for list group element

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/accordion_main_background"
    android:minHeight="50dip"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/screenPromoTaskRootPadding" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/accordionTitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/accordionIndicator"
        android:background="@color/accordionOrangeBackColor"
        android:paddingLeft="2dip"
        android:paddingRight="2dip"
        android:textColor="@color/blackTextColor"
        android:textSize="@dimen/accordMainTextSize" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/accordionIndicator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_up_np" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and in Activity. adaptedDataCollection was just a List which contains data for ExpandableListAdapter. Also it is fragment of implementation of Accordion so list group will collapse other elements after one selected.

```
ExpandableListView accordion = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.accordion);
accordion.setOnGroupClickListener(this);

@Override
public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView paramExpandableListView, View paramView, int paramInt, long paramLong) {
    ImageView icon=(ImageView)paramView.findViewById(R.id.accordionIndicator);
    for (int i = 0; i < adapterDataCollection.size(); i++) {
        if (i == paramInt) {
            if (paramExpandableListView.isGroupExpanded(i)) {
                paramExpandableListView.collapseGroup(i);
                icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_up_np);
            } else {
                paramExpandableListView.expandGroup(i);
                icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_down_np);
            }
        } else {
            paramExpandableListView.collapseGroup(i);
            icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_up_np);
        }
    }
    paramExpandableListView.invalidate();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use 9 patch image for arrow. You can refer bellow image.

[image: right_arrow_9_patch_image]

and for down arrow you can use below image

[image: down_arrow_9_patch_image]

**Don`t forget** to append ".9" to the image name like 
"**your_image_name.9.png**"

Comment: Very helpful answer!

Answer (score 1):

you can set indicator height by [layer-list]
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:bottom="2dp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/shrink"
        android:top="2dp"/>

</layer-list>
```

selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/layer_shrink" android:state_expanded="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look the view that your are using on your custom_group_layout.xml when you inflate it on your  `getGroupView()` of your adapterClass. The view of your indicator maybe has a fill_parent and that's why your item is stretching his icon when you group contains more lines of text.

[An example](http://en.wikicode.org/index.php/Custom_ExpandableListView)